# How to retain newline using localizedStringForKey

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization

I want to make some localization on my application, but my problem is that the localized strings which contain new lines processed without new line. 
Example:

```
+ (NSString *)stringForKey:(NSString *)key {
    NSString *selectedLanguage = [Localization selectedLanguage];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:selectedLanguage ofType:@"lproj"];

    NSBundle *languageBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
    NSString *str = [languageBundle localizedStringForKey:key value:@"" table:nil];

    return str;
}
```

Example file:

```
"key to translate" = "translated \n key";
```

Result which I expect for function call `[Localization stringForKey:@"key to translate"]` is `"translated \n key"` instead I got "`translated key"`.

I have no problem about reaching the file and getting the string, my problem is that the string doesn't contain new line.

Is there solution for that? Thanks for your time.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. `"key to translate" = "translated \n key";` in the Strings file works just fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

For some reasons I haven't fully grasp yet, \n doesn't work every time.

Using \r (carriage return) instead of \n should fix your problem!

Comment: This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Put extra `\` if you want to keep `\n` in the string

```
"key to translate" = "translated \\n key";
```

output is : `translated \n key`